# error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token on Ionic (React.js)

Tags: android, reactjs, ionic-framework

I'm using ionic version 7.2.0 and node v20.10.0 I created an Ionic application with the React.js framework on my Project

```
import { IonAvatar, IonButton, IonButtons, IonCard, IonCardContent, IonCardHeader, IonChip, IonContent, IonHeader, IonIcon, IonImg, IonItem, IonLabel, IonMenuButton, IonModal, IonPage, IonRefresher, IonRefresherContent, IonSearchbar, IonSkeletonText, IonTitle, IonToolbar, useIonAlert, useIonToast, useIonViewDidEnter, useIonViewWillEnter } from '@ionic/react';
import { closeCircle, trashBinOutline } from 'ionicons/icons';
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';

const ListScreen: React.FC = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);
  const [users, setUsers] = useState<any[]>([]);
  const [showAlert] = useIonAlert();
  const [showToast] = useIonToast();
  const [selectedUser, setSelectedUser] = useState<any>(null);
  const modalSheet = useRef<HTMLIonModalElement>(null);

  useIonViewWillEnter(async () => {
    const users = await getUser();
    setUsers(users);
    setLoading(false);
  }, []);


  const getUser = async () => {
    const data = await fetch('https://randomuser.me/api?results=20');
    const users = await data.json();
    return users.results;
  }

  const clearList = () => {
    showAlert({
      header: 'Confirm!',
      message: 'Anda yakin ingin hapus semua?',
      buttons: [
        { text: 'Cancel', role: 'cancel' },
        {
          text: 'Hapus',
          handler: () => {
            setUsers([]);
            showToast({
              message: 'Terhapus Semua',
              duration: 2000,
              color: 'danger'
            })
          }
        }
      ]
    })
  };

  const doRefresh = async (event: any) => {
    const data = await getUser();
    setUsers(data);
    event.detail.complete();
  }

  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonHeader>
        <IonToolbar color={'primary'}>
          <IonButtons slot={'start'}>
            <IonMenuButton />
          </IonButtons>
          <IonTitle>Page List</IonTitle>
          <IonButtons slot={'end'}>
            <IonButtons onClick={clearList}>
              <IonIcon slot={'icon-only'} icon={trashBinOutline} />
            </IonButtons>
          </IonButtons>
        </IonToolbar>
        <IonToolbar color={'primary'}>
          <IonSearchbar showClearButton="always" placeholder="Cari Pesan"></IonSearchbar>
        </IonToolbar>
      </IonHeader>
      <IonContent className='ion-padding'>
        <>
          <IonRefresher slot='fixed' onIonRefresh={(ev) => doRefresh(ev)}>
            <IonRefresherContent />
          </IonRefresher>
          {
            loading && (
              [...Array(20)].map((_, index) => {
                <IonCard key={index}>
                  <IonCardContent className='ion-no-padding'>
                    <IonItem lines='none'>
                      <IonAvatar slot='start'>
                        <IonSkeletonText />
                      </IonAvatar>
                      <IonLabel>
                        <IonSkeletonText animated style={{ width: '150px' }} />
                        <p>
                          <IonSkeletonText />
                        </p>
                      </IonLabel>
                      <IonChip slot='end' color={'primary'}></IonChip>
                    </IonItem>
                  </IonCardContent>
                </IonCard>
              })
            )}
          {
            users.map((user, index) => (
              <IonCard key={index} onClick={() => setSelectedUser(user)}>
                <IonCardContent className='ion-no-padding'>
                  <IonItem lines='none'>
                    <IonAvatar slot='start'>
                      <IonImg src={user.picture.thumbnail} />
                    </IonAvatar>
                    <IonLabel>
                      {user.name.first} {user.name.last}
                      <p>{user.email}</p>
                    </IonLabel>
                    <IonChip slot='end' color={'primary'}>
                      {user.nat}
                    </IonChip>
                  </IonItem>
                </IonCardContent>
              </IonCard>
            ))}

          <IonModal
            ref={modalSheet}
            initialBreakpoint={0.25}
            breakpoints={[0.25, 0.5, 0.75]}
            backdropBreakpoint={1}
            isOpen={selectedUser !== null}
            onIonModalDidDismiss={() => setSelectedUser(null)}
            handleBehavior="cycle"
          >
            <IonHeader>
              <IonToolbar color={'primary'}>
                <IonButtons slot={'start'}>
                  <IonButton onClick={() => modalSheet.current?.dismiss()}>
                    <IonIcon
                      icon={closeCircle}
                      size="large"
                    />
                  </IonButton>
                </IonButtons>
                <IonTitle>
                  {selectedUser?.name.first} {selectedUser?.name.last}
                </IonTitle>
              </IonToolbar>
            </IonHeader>
            <IonContent className="ion-padding">
              Lorem, ipsum.
            </IonContent>
          </IonModal>
        </>
      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  );
};

export default ListScreen;
```

that is my code with the name ListScreen.tsx the problem is when I run it and on the Google Chrome Browser everything runs fine but when I run it on the Android Emulator Pixel 6 Pro API 29 on my Android screen it only displays a blank screen (Blank) and when I inspect it elment I get a red line error in the code section

```
<IonButton onClick={() => modalSheet.current?.dismiss()}>
```

with the error message "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ."
I ask for help, what is the problem and how to solve it?

I've been looking for answers for almost 2 days and the error still persists. Can anyone help me?